# How control mybatis‘s localCache?

Tags: mybatis

I use mybatis version 3.4.0 in my project with postgre sql. There is a id column
is serial type (auto increate primary key column).

I write the mapper's generateId method to get the serial value:

mapper interface:

```
public interface DemoTableNameMapper {

    long generateId();
    ...
```

mapper.xml:

```
<select id="generateId" resultType="long">
    SELECT nextval('"public".demo_table_name_id_seq'::regclass)
</select>
```

But when I call the mapper's generateId method **twice** want to get two ID value, I find **I get the SAME value!!!**

Then I trace into mybatis's source code, I found it's **mybatis' localCache return the previous generated ID value.**

To work around with this problem, I change my generate's declare and implementation.

interface:

```
public interface DemoTableNameMapper {

    /**
     * 产生新的主表的ID
     * 注：因在一次事务中需多次调用，需通过混淆参数来避免命中 mybatis 的 localCache
     * @return
     */
    long generateId(@Param("dummyid") String dummyid);
    ...
```

mapper.xml:

```
<select id="generateId" resultType="long">
    SELECT nextval('"public".demo_table_name_id_seq'::regclass)
    WHERE #{dummyid}=#{dummyid}
</select>
```

My question is:
**Is there a better way to interact with mybatis's localCache?**

---

I change mapper.xml this way:

```
<select id="generateId" resultType="long" useCache="false" flushCache="true">
    SELECT nextval('"public".demo_table_name_id_seq'::regclass)
</select>
```

**it work!!!**

Answer (score 2):

By Default, the localSessionScope is session - So If you make the call twice or N times till the cache clears in the session, it returns you the same value.

If you set localSessionScope as STATEMENT. Every time the new next val is returned.

```
localCacheScope=STATEMENT
```

Alternative way is to clear Cache - (make sure if its ok for the performance), after the first call - by calling

```
clearCache()
```

Refer Here for complete details - [MyBatis Documentation](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/java-api.html)

Comment: Thanks. My reputation is too low, so I can't mark agreement with you. sorry!